# Most frequent y value from the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

What is the fastest way to get one of the y value from graph which occurs most frequently? I have only the local highest and lowest values. I need only one (random) y value.

For example if I have graph like this:

[image]

The most frequent y values can be 0 or 1 (as I said, I need only one).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have points or just y values? Are the points given in some particular order?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it. I have only y values, and they are sorted from beginning to end (left to right in image - [0, 2, -2, 6, 0]).

Comment: Technically `2` occurs only 3 times since it is a maxima.

Comment: It's 1D array and the values are in pairs (array for example image is [0, 2, -2, 6, 0]). Values are not sorted by coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a horizontal sweep line that moves from bottom to top. Initially, it meets the graph 0 times. If it crosses a minimum, it starts meeting the curve twice more than before. If it crosses a maximum, it starts meeting the curve twice less. If meets an endpoint, it starts meeting the curve one time more or one time less depending on the type of point next to it.

Actually, minima and maxima are alternating, so that you can tell the increments by just looking at the parity of the local extrema.

So you can find the solution by sorting the extrema values together with an increment.

```
Extrema/increments
  0  2 -2  6  0
 +1 -2 +2 -2 +1

Sorted extrema/increments
 -2  0  0  2  6
 +2 +1 +1 -2 -2

Number of intersections (prefix sum of the increments)
0  2  3  4  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reduced to the following segments problem:

Given a set of 1d segments, find a value that is contained in the maximal number of segments.

This can be solved by sorting all segment endpoints, and then scanning them. During the scan, one knows the "depth" of every scanned range, and the maximum depth range can be found in one pass.

In your example, the segments are:

```
[0,2] [-2,2] [-2,6] [0,6]
```

The ordered list of endpoints:

```
[-2, [-2, [0, [0, 2], 2], 6], 6]
```

As you can see, the max depth (=4) is obtained between `[0` and `2]`.

Comment: The result is wrong, as Alexandru Barbarosie mentioned, 2 is occurs only 3 times not 4.

Comment: @user1518183: I didn't say 2 is the final answer. Any points in the interior of [0,2] is a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a value between 0 inclusive and 2 exclusive, `[0; 2[`

Here's an example of how to calculate it.

y values = `0, 2, -2, 6, 0`

From this you build the range list

- a: `[0; 2]`
- b: `]2; -2]`
- c: `]-2; 6]`
- d: `]6; 0]`

Arrange the possible values from the range list on a sorted list

```
[-2, ]-2, [0, ]2, [2, ]6, [6  // [ is inclusive and ] is exclusive
```

They have initially the score 0

```
  0    0   0   0   0   0   0
[-2, ]-2, [0, ]2, [2, ]6, [6
```

Iterate the range list and give scores to each possible value if they are in the range.

range a: `[0; 2]`

```
  0    0   1   1   1   0   0
[-2, ]-2, [0, ]2, [2, ]6, [6
```

range b: `]2; -2]`

```
  1    1   2   2   1   0   0
[-2, ]-2, [0, ]2, [2, ]6, [6
```

range c: `]-2; 6]`

```
  1    2   3   3   2   1   1
[-2, ]-2, [0, ]2, [2, ]6, [6
```

range d: `]6; 0]`

```
  1    2   4   4   3   2   1
[-2, ]-2, [0, ]2, [2, ]6, [6
```

The range `[0;2[` has value 4 which is the max